Magento 2.4.2 Remove file from head block using observer and layout update xml
I am trying to use an observer to remove a file(s) from the head block before page load.
I have tried using the events:
layout_generate_blocks_after
layout_load_before

In my code below, the first attempt using the addUpdate() method with an XML string runs, but the file persists in the head of the page.
The second attempt trying to get the head block, the block doesnt ever exist.
/** @var Layout $layout */
            $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

            $layoutUpdateXml = '<referenceBlock name="head"><action method="removeItem">
                <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">css</argument>
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">css/all.css</argument>
            </action></referenceBlock>';

            // Add the layout update XML
            $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate($layoutUpdateXml);


            $headBlock = $layout->getBlock('head');
            if ($headBlock) {
                // Files to remove (example)
                $filesToRemove = [
                    'css/all.css'
                ];

                foreach ($filesToRemove as $file) {
                    $type = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'css' ? 'css' : 'js';
                    $headBlock->removeItem($type, $file);
                }
            }

            return $this;

I have used several variations of xml, including the use of:

    <referenceBlock name="head"><remove src="css/all.css"/></referenceBlock>

And:
    <referenceBlock name="head"><action method="removeItem"><type>css</type><name>css/all.css</name></action></referenceBlock>

The second XML using type throws an error depending on which event I use.
